# Is it possible to use two orderby conditions in a firebase query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview. In that I'm displaying data from Firebase Realtime DB.
It is a grocery App. I have Fruits, vegetables and Provisional Items.
I have used (My firebase path.... child(..).orderbyChild("Category").equalto("Fruits").

Upto this, it's working fine. I'm getting Fruits alone.

Next thing is, I need to keep all the not in stock products at the bottom of my recycler view. If I add one more orderbyChild("NotInStock"), the app is crashing.

Is there any way to solve this or alternate way to achieve this..
Need some help here.

Comment: Some of the code would be hepful. How/where do you store the data and how do you propagate them to the adapter.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what you expect to happen. A detailed example would be very helpful

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For example, you could create `"Category_NotInStock": "Fruits_True"` and filter on that. For a longer example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

Per documentation of [#orderByChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#orderbychild):

> Queries can only order by one key at a time. Calling orderByChild() multiple times on the same query is an error.

This is further emphasized in the "Sorting Data" section under their [Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) page:

> You can only use **one** order-by method at a time. Calling an order-by method multiple times in the same query throws an error.

In a typical SQL environment, it'd be a simple `ORDER BY NotInStock ASC, Category`. As far as alternative approaches (bearing in mind firebase's limitations):

1. You can query the relevant data twice, first for in-stock items, then again for out-of-stock once you've exhausted the "in-stock" data.
2. You can query all of the data at once, and then sort/categorize the data further once you have retrieved it from firebase.
3. You can follow further additional approaches outlined in the above linked  duplicate question: [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)